# How to lazy load vue2 component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is it possible to do that?

**Tried**

```
 components: {
  Fibonacci: () => import('./Fibonacci.vue')
 }
```

But Eslint warning about `import` (Parsing error: Unexpected token import).
What need to change?

*upd:*

```
new Vue({
 components: { 
  Fibonacci: () => import('./Fibonacci.vue')
 }
)}
```

Comment: could you please provide your hole code - normally this is the correct coding and it's possible, but without your code we can't help you

Comment: do you have plugin ```eslint-plugin-vue``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this plugin: https://github.com/xunleif2e/vue-lazy-component

If you mean a page component, I think you should use vue-router if you want to lazy load a component.

BTW, i don't see components option accept a function.

```
components?: { [key: string]: Component<any, any, any, any> | AsyncComponent<any, any, any, any> };
```